# Symfony2 doctrine and response

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine

I have a little problem, I'm trying to send a json response, but all I get is a empty object all the time.

So here is my code:

```
//Get the data from DB
$template = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('EVRYgroBundle:Template')
    ->findOneBy(
        array('active' => 1)
        );

    if (!$template) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No product found for id '
        );
    }

  //Send the response
 $response = new Response();
 $response->setContent(json_encode($template));
 return $response;
```

And when I'm viewing it all it shows is {}
And I have also tried with the jsonResponse and with this code:

```
$response = new JsonResponse();
$response->setData($template);
```

And I have no idea what i'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the problem, the problem was that some variables that holds the information from the db was set to protected and not public.

Comment: Do you not have all of the getters and setters?

Answer (score 1):

json_encode expects an array as first parameter to be given in. When you call it with an object the public properties will may be displayed. To keep the properties protected (as they should be) you can add a expose function to your entity:

```
/**
 * delivers all properties and values of the entity easily
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function expose()
{
    return get_object_vars($this);
}
```

and then call

```
$response->setData(json_encode($template->expose()));
```

This way you keep your entity clean with only access via getter and setter methods and you can access all properties via json still.